# Who will be horrified by the Worldbuilding site?

Tags: dystopia, horror

Who will be horrified (or angered or distressed) on reading or knowing of the existence of the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange site or any post(s) present on it?

By 'who will', I mean any futuristic/magical/real/hypothetical/etc being(s)/race(s)/world(s)/etc.

---

Creative answers are welcome, but don't weave too much of a story (unless it's worth it). You may refer to the horrifying capacity of any particular post (question, answer or even comment) on WB SE. You are also encouraged to refer to popular fictional characters.

Comment: P.S. I have absolutely no idea how to tag this one; tag suggestions are welcome.

Comment: While interesting, I don't see any way to determine the 'right' answer to this question, which makes it 'opinion-based'. However, this seems like it might go over better in meta, or even more in chat.

Comment: Thoughtcrime....all of it. Food for the joycamp, the thinkpol will drive you there directly.

Comment: @kingledion Maybe one can consider broadening the scope if that is the consensus. I had the same doubt when posting this.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code If you are in doubt when posting a question on WorldBuilding you can use the [Sandbox](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) on the Meta. There you can get feedback on things like the scope, style, grammar, ... all this general stuff before releasing it onto the Main Site.

Comment: @HDE Is there any way I can edit the post so that it fits in the scope?

Comment: This is kinda meta...and opinion based--this is very open-ended, so much so that it's hard to answer!

Comment: Probably the creators - at least once it's been infiltrated and turned into a perverted joke of it's former ambitious self.

Comment: @kingledion There was once a question that said some random alien species builds rooms with two doors. Why do they do so? Doesn't that kind of question lack an objective answer criterion?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code It is really hard to directly compare question to question. The same people do not vote on each question, so if you get a tough group of voters, your question could get closed while another similar one does not. This is a feature of Stack Exchange, and you just have to accept that this is how it is. Democracy (SE variant) gives the best results averaged over the long run, but doesn't always stand up to scrutiny on a case by case basis.

Comment: @kingledion Thanks. It turns out that question also did get closed later in spite of gathering so many upvotes. http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/72964/why-would-a-civilization-outfit-buildings-with-separate-portals-for-entering-and#

Answer (score 4):

Wonderfully creative authors who worked hard on fantastic concepts...and never get quoted or credited on the site.

(Side glance toward [F.M. Busby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F._M._Busby) and [Cordwainer Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cordwainer_Smith))

Comment: LMFAO!! I think you are right!

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Your answer, while probably true, is so short that it has made it to the review queue for low quality answers. As such, there is a risk that it gets deleted if you do not flesh it out. The reason is, as kingledion points out, is that it would fit better as a comment than a full answer.

Answer (score 2):

**A zealot with the knowledge of what truth is and that the truth and only the truth should be teached and discussed.**

All those blasphemous ideas on this site only spread *misinformation* about the world we are living. The world functions **exactly** as described in the <insert holy scripture here> and anything which even discusses those falsehoods, perverted thoughts and *vile lies* should be banned, burned and the readers should be punished !!!!!

Comment: Bah. This answer is apostacy. Nevertheless, +1 for good formatting as the mighty Zorg decreed in the ancient scrolls of Cleveland.

Comment: @user535733 Downvote, someone felt addressed....

Comment: This is actually quite true. I had a 'zealot' have a go at one of my questions asking about if clones have fingerprints or maybe it was the other clone question on how to grow them fast. Either way, he earned my first and only down vote that day when he failed to answer the question and tried to answer instead with if <insert any religion here> would even allow such a sacrilegious unethical demon-possessed creature to exist...OK, I added the last part. I was actually surprised I hadn't seen more answers like that until I realised the moderators are probably very good at removing them.

Answer (score 1):

Different race(s) or being(s) seeing tech leaks on the site. Almost like Wiki-leaks. This causes interstellar wars, espionage etc.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Since your answer is so short, it has made it to the review queue for low quality; as such, there is a risk that your answer is deleted if you do not flesh it out. As kingledion points out, this answer would be better suited as a comment in it's current state.